# QUdpSocket class does not read last bytes

Tags: qt, udp

I have an application that reads data from QUdp socket.The data comes as chunks with a header, after an header fixed size data and the remaining data.

header=50 bytes

fixed size=300

and the remainder is= <300

in this order.

My apllication runs as;

```
    while(udpSocket->hasPendingDatagrams()) {
        QByteArray datagram;
        datagram.resize(udpSocket->pendingDatagramSize());
        QHostAddress sender;
        quint16 senderPort;

        udpSocket->readDatagram(datagram.data(), datagram.size(),
                                &sender, &senderPort);
        qout << "datagram received from " << sender.toString() << endl;
      }
    }
 }
```

But i can not handle the last remainng bytes

Comment: Check the return value of readDatagram(). My assumption would be that the last chunk isn't detected as complete datagram (haspendingDatagrams returning false) because it's smaller? Check what bytesAvailable() returns.

Comment: yeah frank i think so.it is not detected.what can be the solution

Comment: I presume that this code is within a slot connected to the socket's `readyRead()` signal?